# MongoDb server refuses remote connections

Tags: c#, mongodb

I've installed `MongoDb Community` on Ubuntu and want to connect to it from my other server.

In `/etc/mongod.conf` file, when I comment these lines it works:

```
# security:
#  authorization: 'enabled'
```

But when I uncomment, I get this error:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

bindIp is commented in both cases

```
#  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Right after installation, I've created a user this way:

```
use DataDb

db.createUser({
    user: 'u1',
    pwd: 'secretPassword',
    roles: [{ role: 'readWrite', db:'DataDb'}]
})
```

and my connection string is like this:

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://u1:pass@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:27017/DataDb");
```

What is wrong? thanks.

Comment: Jesus Christ, read the [docs regarding authentication setup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/#procedure). And authentication is not even half the story of securing a public MongoDB server. The very least you need is TLS encryption and some sort of brute force blocker. Furthermore those questions belong to http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg you scare me! It's not secure even if server accept connection from one specific IP and reject all the rest?

Comment: and this worked by apparently removing quotations from `'enabled'`

Comment: That depends. Is your firewall properly set up? How do you prevent IP spoofing? Are we talking of a private network? How is the network separated from the internet? *mumblesQuestionsForHalfAnHour*...